# Are there any connection limits on Windows 7 IIS v7.5?

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7.5

My current development machine is Windows XP, and I use a modified tcpip.sys to allow me to exceed the 10 connection limit built in to IIS. I know that Vista's IIS has the same limit.

Can anyone confirm whether this connection limit is present in Windows 7 IIS as well?

Comment: Are your eferring to the 10 authenticated connection limit in XP, or the 10 half-open connections limit?  It seems that those answering your question are assuming the latter.. which doesn't make a lot of sense regarding IIS on desktop OS's.

Comment: I am referring to the 10 half-open connection limit.

Comment: This question is badly-formed. The (outbound) half-open connection limit from Windows XP SP2 has nothing to do with the (inbound) IIS number-of-requests limit. The accepted answer covers both possibilities, but the question is like asking "what orange is the best pear?"

Comment: @TristanK I framed the question as best as I could with my limited understanding. The issue I was trying to deal with was the IIS connection limit exceeded errors (actually EventID 4226) that you can get when hosting IIS on Windows XP. The reason I assumed half-open connections were the issue was that this is what was patched by the TCPIP.SYS patcher I used (http://www.lvllord.de/?lang=en&url=4226patch/faq), which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the base OS perspective, the limit has gone.

With Vista pre-sp2 it depended on the version. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413110/which-is-the-maximum-number-of-windows-concurrent-tcp-ip-connections/929973#929973

Since Vista SP2 the limitation have been removed from TCPIP.SYS, and has been configurable through a registry key. Windows7 should follow that same behavior ([source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969710) and [for 7](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasp/thread/2afc725f-44fd-4ae1-9eb8-f0c3a0f552bc/), and [here](http://deepxw.blogspot.com/2009/05/say-bye-to-half-open-tcp-connections.html)), but of course we will not know for 7 definitely until RTM since appart from technial there may be license restrictions.

However, [IIS introduces its own limitations](http://www.jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm), depending on the version of the OS. For Windows 7 this limit is between 3 (Home Premium) and 10 (Business, Enterprise & Ultimate) simultaneous connections . Depending on your scenario, it might help to lower the [connection timeout](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Set-Connection-Limits-in-IIS-7-75.aspx) to free up slots sooner.

Comment: Thanks, but interested in Windows 7, not Vista.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update.

Comment: This answer describes *TCP* connections, but does not discuss IIS itself. IIS has a 10-connection limit in any non-server OS. Easily confirmed by testing.

Comment: You are right, I included the info in the answer. For Windows 7, it is not always 10. For "Home Premium" edition the limit is 3.

Answer (score 4):

The connection limit in IIS is NOT THE SAME as the 10 half-port open limit. This is a limit built into IIS and has nothing to do with TCP/IP.  Pay for server or run Apache.

Comment: No need to pay for a server, as I was having no issue with connection limit - only half-open connection limit, which is a solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [special version of TCP-Z](http://www.blogsdna.com/2719/windows-7-tcpipsys-auto-patcher-to-remove-tcpip-connection-limit.htm), a tool for "patching" tcpip.sys, for Windows 7 - an indication that this setting still exists in Microsoft new operating system.

*Disclaimer: it is not advised to change operating system drivers.*

Comment: You're confusing the "10 connection limit" of Desktop OS's with the "10 half-open connection limit" that was imposed as a security restriction.  I'm not sure which the question asker was referring to.  The "10 connection limit" is imposed on authenticated connections to prevent Desktop IIS from being used as a server.

Comment: The question itself is a little confusing. The asked writes "IIS connection limit" (?) and "patching tcpip.sys", so I deduced he was referring to this limit.

Comment: I am referring to the 10 half-open connection limit. The same limit that was fixed by this Win XP patch: http://www.lvllord.de/?url=tools.

Comment: You deduced correctly. thanks for the link splattne, sounds like the limit is still there :(

Comment: I confirmed with this tool that on Windows 7 the limit is still 10.

Comment: Clarification - the tool shows what the limit WOULD be if it is turned on by the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\EnableConnectionRateLimiting=1

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I stand corrected, there is a 10 concurrent connection HTTP limit, confirmed by testing.

Comment: What is the basis for your statement that there is no concurrent connection limit in Windows 7 IIS? Is it an assumption based on your knowledge of Vista, or have you confirmed it to be the case?

Comment: My original screenshot was against IIS7 server, not IIS 7.5 client due to a typo in hostname. Apologies.

Answer (score -1):

Pleae see this link, and how to get more concurrent connections in IIS.

http://community.psion.com/knowledge/w/knowledgebase/1227.a-r-c-increase-iis-connection-limits.aspx

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: -1: The information in the linked article is incorrect.