# Setting the maximum amount of connections on IIS5 and Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, iis

I've tried installing a 'quick and dirty' website in our LAN (just so I can publish an RSS feed which will be used internally by our team) by installing IIS 5 on an old Windows XP SP2 machine. The 'website' works, but attempting to access the page containing the RSS results all too often in a "max connections exceeded" error message.

Is there a way to increase the amount of maximum connections in IIS v5.1?

Answer (score 2):

There are two utilities that can help you with this:

[TCP-Z](http://deepxw.blogspot.com/2009/01/tcp-z-center.html)

[Update of TCPIP.SYS](http://www.lvllord.de/)

You'll find some more info in a similar question: [Are there any connection limits on Windows 7 IIS v7.5?](https://serverfault.com/questions/21131/are-there-any-connection-limits-on-windows-7-iis-v7-5).

Another thing you can do, which degrades performance slightly, is to either turn off keep-alives in IIS, or set the keep-alive timeout very low, e.g., 5 seconds. This doesn't give you more half-open connections, but means the ones available will only be used for a short amount of time. This would still only allow 10 concurrent users, but the odds of concurrency get much lower when you shorten or disable the keep-alives.