# Is it wrong to buy windows 7 professional and use it as an web server because it has IIS in a company?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, windows-7, web-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What about Windows 7 as a web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/133772/what-about-windows-7-as-a-web-server)

What would be wrong with using low cost windows 7 pro for an intranet web application if I can disable other services on the server manually to cut some costs?

Windows server is way more expensive as I know.

Comment: Windows 7 is not a server OS so it's outside of our FAQ in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at those Limits:
http://www.jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm

> Windows 7 (IIS v7.5) Starter:   No IIS  Home Basic:   No IIS Home
>   Premium:   simultaneous request execution limit of 3, allows multiple
>   sites   Business:   simultaneous request execution limit of 10, allows
>   multiple sites   Enterprise:   simultaneous request execution limit of
>   10, allows multiple sites   Ultimate:   simultaneous request execution
>   limit of 10, allows multiple sites

Also, I seem to recall that the EULA forbids to use Client operating Systems as "Server", and you'll also running on "Client Hardware", which could be a pitfall.