# What are the pit-falls of using Windows 7 as a web server?

Tags: windows-7, web-server, iis-7.5

It obviously uses more memory (with the fancy themes), but from what I have ready, IIS7.5 is fully functioning.  I use it for a dev server, but what about a full-on prod server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 7 Ultimate allows a max of 20 concurrent connections to any piece of software running on the machine.  Not sure, but this may be lower for lesser editions of Windows 7.  Go to Start | Run and type in `winver`, then scroll down to where it says Device Connections to see how many are allowed (by license) for your edition.

Based on [**this thread**](http://forums.iis.net/t/1055753.aspx) IIS7.5 has a limit of 10 concurrently executing requests, but no max on concurrent connections.

On top of that, your next biggest issue is running a production system on workstation class hardware.  This is typically not recommended, although you'll need to gauge that based on your environment and your requirements.

Comment: A couple of notes. First is that `winver` doesn't say anything about maximum concurrent suggestions here (7 Ultimate x64), and second is that there is no Start->Run in Windows 7. You probably meant the search box. Also, client operating systems will run on server hardware.

Comment: @fahadsadah: There is a Start->Run if you turn it back on. It's just turned off by default. Also, most people asking about running Win7 as a production server are probably running it on older consumer grade hardware too (might not be the case here, but commonly).

Comment: Of course it's going to be tough to use up all 10 requests by yourself since client OSes are single user at a time by license.  That's the reason yuo can switch users on windows xp and up but you can't remote desktop with more than 1 user

Comment: This answered everything! Thanks. Looks like I won't be using 7 outside of dev.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest pitfall is not technical. Running a production, multi-user IIS installation on Windows 7 breaks the end user licensing agreement and you are on very shaky ground legally.

Comment: Where exactly? Please can you quote the relevant portion?

Comment: @fahadsadah Windows 7 EULA - "Unless otherwise provided in these license terms, only one user may use the software at a time." Clause 2.c in Enterprise; 2.d in Home versions.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, go away for 10 minutes and you miss important stuff...

Comment: FWIW, Microsoft would be on very shaky ground legally to sue you claiming that making a HTTP connection to a process running on the software is the same as using the software.

Comment: but is running IIS really allowing "multiple users access"? If it's running as a system process, it would seem as though to me that it's still just one "user"

Comment: How many users will have access to the website? If the answer is more than 1, you have yourself a multi-user system. You are thinking like technicians and not like lawyers. From their standpoint IIS is a component of the software, and therefore the same rules apply.

Comment: 'Website' and 'system' are two completely seperate things, and I doubt that there are many non-technical lawyers who would not see them as such.

Comment: In any case, we're missing the wood for the trees here. Microsoft will not waste their time suing over an unclear issue, and evidently not for much, seeing as in their eyes, the company can't afford server software/hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This should help, its for Windows Vista (i.e. IIS 7), but should be similar:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/479/iis-70-features-and-vista-editions/

Seems that the main issue is the limit on concurrent network connections.  The max for the edition that comes with Vista is 10.  Windows server is unlimited.

---

Seems like you might also want to check: [Are there any connection limits on Windows 7 IIS v7.5?](https://serverfault.com/questions/21131/are-there-any-connection-limits-on-windows-7-iis-v7-5)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  It just links out to vista related article and the bottom link is old and doesn't have any news about windows 7.

Comment: Maybe not exactly, but it points you in the right direction.  If the technical limitation in IIS 5.1 (Windows XP) and IIS 7 (Vista) was connection limits, its likely that the IIS 7.5 has similar issues, and would be something specific for you to research.