# How is Windows Server different from regular Windows?

Tags: windows

I can run IIS on a normal installation, what is so different about windows server?

Comment: The license agreement.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Several key areas:

- Amount of memory supported
- Number of processors supported
- Number of network connections may be greater than 10
- Some apps do an OS version check, and they won't install unless it's the proper server version (as previously mentioned)
- By default, the server OS is configured to give priority to background apps/services and the client OS is configured to give priority to foreground apps. This can be configured, however.
- There are some services (Microsoft created) that are only permitted to run on the server OS (DNS, DHCP, Active Directory, PKI, etc.) as previously mentioned.

Comment: Some apps do an OS version check and won't install if it is a server.  iTunes, for example.

Comment: True, Richard. Zune software is the same way. There's a way to hack it, but it's not any fun.

Comment: @Bubby4j: I think they 10 "network connections" actually refers to an IIS limitation.  There's no OS limitation that prevents you from accepting 100 or more TCP connections in the same machine (or even process for that matter).

Answer (score 7):

Number of connections, see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/21131/are-there-any-connection-limits-on-windows-7-iis-v7-5), it can be gotten around. Performance maybe, since Windows desktop OS's are optimized for foreground apps, i.e. all those Notepads, IE's, etc, where server OS's are optimized for services.

In short, it's fine for development and testing, but not recommended for serious production.

Answer (score 4):

Some software like SQL Server Enterprise Edition, Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server are server products that will specifically run on Windows Server.

Also, it can do DNS, DHCP, VPN, Print Server, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're limited to 10 connections and 1 website with IIS on a desktop version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**some of the key features of the windows server:**

1. Active directory:
2. File and Storage:
3. DHCP: Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol:
4. print services:
5. Windows Update Services:

Windows is used for analysis and other work at offices, schools, etc., but the Windows server runs services people use across a specific network.
Windows Server comes with a desktop choice, and it is suggested to establish Windows Server without GUI to decrease the costs of running the server.
The difference between IIS in windows & windows servers is that you could use remote management to join the remote server in the server OS while the client OS is unavailable.

Comment: this was and is already stated in the previous answer. what do you try to tell?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).