# What are the differences between a server and regular edition of windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-7, diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is Windows Server different from regular Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/158610/how-is-windows-server-different-from-regular-windows)

What are the differences between a server edition of windows (such as Windows Server 2008) and a regular version of windows (Like windows 7 ultimate, with the windows classic theme)? Could you use Windows 7 as a cheap server OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from restricting number of CPUs and amount of RAM, Windows 7 also has a maximum connection limit (10, I think).
Depending on what you are trying to do, this will kick in.