# What is the difference between Sever and Consumer OS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is Windows Server different from regular Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/158610/how-is-windows-server-different-from-regular-windows)

**What is the difference between server and consumer operating systems - the examples I have in mind being Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2?**

Why shouldn't I run Windows 7 on my server? There are a few good questions on here explaining the intricacies of consumer and server grade hardware, but I couldn't find much on operating systems aside from server operating systems not being pre-loaded with consumer software and features like media player, etc.

Comment: As well as the answers below, you may even struggle to find drivers for all the components of your server in a desktop os - for instance I've installed XP on a couple of Dell 9G servers in the past but had to install a graphics driver from someone like IBM or HP to get the display right.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 has a limit to the number of concurrent connections allowed to network services like file shares, print shares, IIS sessions, etc. These limits are low (20 I think), meaning that the client OS is not suitable for use as a server.

Also, roles like DHCP, DNS, AD DS, etc cannot be installed on a client OS, meaning that Windows 7's usefulness as a server is, essentially, nonexistent.

Comment: Also, the major reason for a corporation to have Windows Servers at all is to make them act as Domain Controllers (servers that co-ordinate and help manage large numbers of windows client machines). Windows 7 cannot act as a Domain Controller.

Comment: @ItsGC I listed that when I said `AD DS` - which means `Active Directory Domain Services`. :)

Comment: you're throwing a bunch of acronyms at a guy that can't even tell what a server is. I felt that particular technology deserved more than 4 characters, since the entire enterprise strategy of Microsoft has been based on it for the past 25 years.

Comment: @ItsGC this is a site for professionals. I answer questions assuming a basic level if competency. Or at least a the ability to google things.

Comment: I admire the attitude but a quick tour of the unanswered questions hints at a less-than-ideal situation on this regard:) I did upvote your answer tho.

Comment: @ItsGC If you reduce the quality of a community to the lowest common denominator, then you're going to be left with trash. If the OP can't take the time to google those industry-standard acronyms, then they really don't belong here :)

Comment: I'd go even further and say that this question doesn't belong at all here. If this is a community targeted to IT Professionals, this is not an acceptable level of knowledge in the first place.